# What is a MOJO codec and how can it be used with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, codec

NComputing VCast has this MOJO format that can play fast on their thin clients.
As described here: https://support.ncomputing.com/portal/en/kb/articles/vcast-what-is-the-difference-between-web-media-and-mojo

When I installed it, it has this ffmpeg installer that was executed, so I assume it uses ffmpeg under  the hood to convert MP4 to MOJO format.

However I have been trying to find what is this MOJO video format and how can I encoded videos without using the context menu action and instead run it from command line using ffmpeg.

Anybody knows a hint on this MOJO video format?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the output for the `ffprobe`

```
ffprobe version N-82151-g1e660fe Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, avi, from '.\sample.mp4.hd.mojo':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:37:28.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10461 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 960x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9745 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 20 tbn, 20 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
```

Comment: Never heard of it. No mention of "mojo" in FFmpeg source code. Got a sample file? Where is it getting ffmpeg from? Or are they distributing their own build of ffmpeg?

Comment: Try ffprobe it?

Comment: @TomYan I updated the original post with the ffprobe output, it looks like it's motion jpeg

Comment: You can see more detailed info with `ffprobe -show_streams -show_format input.avi`.

Comment: So you say this, “…can play fast on their thin clients.” but the code shows as “mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D)” So one thing is not in conflict with another, but MJPEG is an ancient format. Good format, but not as well compressed and x264 or x265 which modern CPUs can handle. I mean, A tiny Chromecase can decode x265. So before deeply exploring this `.mojo` stuff think about what you want/need and how a modern codec might fulfill that need. I am all for exploring, but still… No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 not sure what you mean, but the MJPG format contained in mojo is just the video file that the thin client can play, so it's not something that I choose to use and encode at all. I am not really sure why these thin clients from NComputing is "hardwired" to play mojo format only, playing anything else is just slow and like just few fps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NComputing MOJO* format is a variant MJPEG video format which can be generated with this script:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -vcodec mjpeg -vf scale=min'(960,iw)':-1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 22050 -ac 2 -r 20 -q:v 8 -f avi "output.mojo"
```

Other configuration setting could be found at the installation dir, usually here:
`C:\Program Files\NComputing\vSpace Server Software\MojoStreaming`

With the following settings:

1. High quality `-q:v 2`
2. Standard quality `-q:v 5`
3. Low quality `-q:v 8`

The `.mojo` extension is used to be able to be played by the NComputing MOJO player.